# What would you call or how would you describe this weapon?

Tags: image-identification

I watched a Chinese movie in which the protagonist used this weapon. Its blade part can rotate like a drill.

[image: Square-section weapon similar to a sword]

I was wondering if you know the name of this kind of weapon or how would you describe its appearance?
I tried:

> It’s a skinny mace with connected stone cubes for its blade part and a sharp cone on top.

But I think my description will likely cause confusion. I would appreciate it if you could help me out.

Comment: This doesn't look like an actual weapon to me, just something invented for visual effect by the props designer. Fantasy and pseudo-historical movies rarely use plausible weapons--they just don't look exciting enough.

Comment: I would describe it first and foremost as a "sword" because it looks like a sword. It has a guard, a scabbard, a "blade", a grip, and a pommel. A mace typically doesn't have all those features. "A sword with a blade of connected stone cubes that spin as a drill would"

Comment: A capped baton of 19 rectangular cuboids with a square hand guard, wrapped pommel and matching scabbard.

Comment: You might want to do a Google search on the name of the movie and _sword_ or _mace_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got a couple of hits with "kang long mace":

> [The pagoda whip, mace, sword, Longquan KANGLONG pattern steel, fine sword, sword](http://www.vtanghub.com/emall/goods/020960.html)
>
> [The pagoda whip KANGLONG mace cold weapon pattern steel Tang sword Longquan sword not of edge (custom)](http://www.globals.me/item.html?id=tb532663897991&title=The%20pagoda%20whip%20KANGLONG%20mace%20cold%20weapon%20pattern%20steel%20&key=Cold%20weapon)
>
> [[Military typhoon] movie Babel Empire Detective / Di Renjie selected hand Kang Long mace (hand pattern steel) ancient weapons / collection ~ free shipping ~](https://tw.bid.yahoo.com/item/%E3%80%90%E8%BB%8D%E6%AD%A6%E9%96%80%E3%80%91%E9%9B%BB%E5%BD%B1-%E9%80%9A%E5%A4%A9%E5%B8%9D%E5%9C%8B-%E7%A5%9E%E6%8E%A2-%E7%8B%84%E4%BB%81%E6%9D%B0-%E7%B2%BE%E9%81%B8%E6%89%8B%E5%B7%A5-%E4%BA%A2%E9%BE%8D%E9%94%8F-100048757297)

Unfortunately, I can barely handle English, so you're on your own for translations.  (Or you could ask the Google.)

Beyond that, perhaps a [martial arts](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/) SE might be of more help?